# Show: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left|\int_{1}^{e}\left[\ln(x)\right]^n\:dx \right|= 0 $

Tags: integration, limits, proof-verification, definite-integrals

This is probably an unremarkable result, but I was curious about exploring the following family of definite integrals to see what asymptotic behaviour it as as $n \rightarrow \infty$

$$I_n = \int_{1}^{e}\left[\ln(x)\right]^n\:dx \mbox{ for } n \in \mathbb{N}$$

The method I took:

Employ integration by parts:

\begin{align}
    v'(x) &= 1 & u(x) &= \left[\ln(x)\right]^n \\
    v(x) &= x & u'(x) &= n\left[\ln(x)\right]^{n - 1}\frac{1}{x}
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{align}
    I_n &= \int_{1}^{e}\left[\ln(x)\right]^n\:dx = x \cdot \left[\ln(x)\right]^n \Big|_{1}^{e} - \int_{1}^{e}  x \cdot n\left[\ln(x)\right]^{n - 1}\frac{1}{x} \\
    &= e - n\int_{1}^{e}\left[\ln(x)\right]^{n - 1}\:dx
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{equation}
    I_n = e - nI_{n - 1}
\end{equation}

Where

\begin{equation}
    I_1 = \int_{1}^{e} \ln(x)\:dx = x\left(\ln(x) - 1\right)\Big|_{1}^{e} = 1
\end{equation}

This yields the solution:

\begin{align}
    I_n &= n!\left[(-1)^{n - 1} + e\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 2} \frac{(-1)^i}{(n - i)!} \right] = n!\left(-1\right)^n\left[-1  + e\sum_{i = 2}^{n } \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} \right] \\
    &= n!\left(-1\right)^n\left[-1  + e\sum_{i = 0}^{n } \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} \right] 
\end{align}

We see that:

\begin{equation}
    \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} I_n = n! (-1)^n \left( -1 + e\cdot e^{-1} \right) = 0
\end{equation}

Or

\begin{equation}
    \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{1}^{e}\left[\ln(x)\right]^n\:dx = 0 
\end{equation}

I was wondering if I could have a more technical eye have a look over this to see if the result I've obtained is correct.

Edit - Final result was incorrect and now corrected as per Song's pickup.

Comment: Your mistake is $-1+e\cdot e^{-1} = 1$. It should be $0$. Actually, by dominated convergence theorem, $\int_1^e (\log x)^n dx \to 0$. In the same spirit, we can show $\int_1^A (\log x)^n dx = \mathcal{o}((\log A)^n)$.

Comment: Hi @Song - Yes, indeed- Thank you very much. I will edit my post.

Comment: For a more direct approach leading to the same optimal result, note that, by concavity of the logarithm, for every $1<x<e$, $\ln x<e^{-1}x$ hence $$I_n<e^{-n}\int_1^ex^ndx<e^{-n}\int_0^ex^ndx=\frac e{n+1}$$